# laravel where clause return null even if data exists

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I tried to query for data in user controller  but return only null even when data exist.

```
$user = DB::table('users')->where('email','=','dumitriucristian@yahoo.com')->first();
```

if I do:

```
 $user = DB::table('users')->get();
```

it returns all the data so the db is ok. What it wrong?

Comment: You have to check how data is stored in your database, as an example, `'dumitriucristian@yahoo.com'` !== `'dumitriucristian@yahoo.com '`

Comment: it was just a typo on email value ... pfuuu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That value is not present or you must have a typo in your database. Please check it.